# How to find location of non fatal error in Android's logcat

Tags: android, logcat, android-cursor

I'm getting some non fatal errors on my logcat but no line numbers or anything else that can help me locate the error.

As you can see, I'm getting several, including `Cursor finalized without prior close()` and `Window is full`, but no idea how to find them.

```
09-26 14:20:47.743: W/CursorWindow(2090): Window is full: requested allocation 756 bytes, free space 150 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
09-26 14:20:48.151: D/dalvikvm(2090): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1686K, 3% free 90204K/92076K, paused 108ms, total 112ms
09-26 14:20:48.159: W/CursorWrapperInner(2090): Cursor finalized without prior close()
09-26 14:20:48.163: W/CursorWrapperInner(2090): Cursor finalized without prior close()
09-26 14:20:49.759: D/dalvikvm(2090): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 910K, 2% free 91343K/92436K, paused 115ms, total 115ms
09-26 14:20:51.127: D/dalvikvm(2090): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 731K, 1% free 92661K/93576K, paused 70ms, total 70ms
09-26 14:20:52.195: D/dalvikvm(2090): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 683K, 1% free 94024K/94892K, paused 71ms, total 71ms
09-26 14:20:53.303: D/dalvikvm(2090): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 713K, 1% free 95360K/96256K, paused 77ms, total 77ms
09-26 14:20:54.403: D/dalvikvm(2090): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 706K, 1% free 96702K/97592K, paused 84ms, total 84ms
09-26 14:20:54.755: W/CursorWindow(2090): Window is full: requested allocation 756 bytes, free space 645 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
09-26 14:20:55.559: D/dalvikvm(2090): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 752K, 1% free 98000K/98936K, paused 76ms, total 76ms
```

Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This kind of errors are not exceptions thrown by the program and will therefore not contain a stack-trace. As a general rule of thumb you may find ways to optimize your code by carefully reading the error message and read into the subject concerning the error.

As far as I can see it is a problem with allocation of memory. I don't think you can pinpoint them to a specific position in your execution flow since it will probably occur at different points in execution. You can think about your code to see if you can find some memory optimization possibilities.

If you want to analyze your code thoroughly you may want to use a tool like 'Eclipse MAT'. Read this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMemoryAnalyzer/article.html) to learn how to use the tool

Answer (score 0):

Do a global file search looking for text like ".query(" in your .java files.

That should lead you to places where a Cursor is returned and from there you should be able to determine where they are not being closed.